# Flutter - return data from firebase

Tags: flutter

This code return all documents and where clause not working on load , It's working after navigate to another screen and returned back

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Trips').where('uid',isEqualTo: UserID).snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ''clause not working on load''?

Comment: Hey there, could you add the code for were `UserID` is defined

Comment: It's a class variable

Comment: All data is loaded instead of just the required data , I mean load all data from Trips collection and i want only the data for the specific user